# Files missing after git merge

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

I have read other questions in regards to this, but mine is a peculiar case of losing files in local git, without a trace.

I cloned a repository:

```
 git clone https://github.com/uruddarraju/kubernetes
 cd kubernetes/
```

I did a fetch of upstream for project kubernetes using the following commands:

```
 git remote add upstrm https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes
 git fetch upstrm
```

This brought down a bunch of tags as follows:

```
uruddarraju$ git tag
v1.3.2-beta.0
v1.3.3
v1.3.3-beta.0
v1.3.4
```

I am trying to merge v1.3.4 into the branch tess or remote origin

```
git merge v1.3.4
```

There are a lot of merge conflicts which I have  to resolve, but interestingly I also see that a new file that is added to upstrm/v1.3.4 is now missing in the local file system and I don't see that file in git status either.

How can this be possible ? I was expecting these files to be added as part of the merge but clearly they were not.

```
uruddarraju$ ls pkg/genericapiserver/
resource_encoding_config.go
```

I am looking for the file resource_config.go
I discarded the merge and checked into v1.3.4 to verify if the file is present in that branch:

```
uruddarraju$ git checkout -b merege1.3 v1.3.4
uruddarraju$ ls pkg/genericapiserver
resource_config.go
resource_config_test.go
resource_encoding_config.go
```

I did a git diff on the two branches and I clearly see that the files have been added in upstrm/v1.3.4
I ran the following while I was on v1.3.4

```
uruddarraju$ git diff master --name-status
A       pkg/genericapiserver/resource_config.go
A       pkg/genericapiserver/resource_config_test.go
A       pkg/genericapiserver/resource_encoding_config.go
```

When I do the other way around, bu being on master and doing a diff with v1.3.4, I see:

```
uruddarraju$ git diff v1.3.4 --name-status
D       pkg/genericapiserver/resource_config.go
D       pkg/genericapiserver/resource_config_test.go
D       pkg/genericapiserver/resource_encoding_config.go
```

**EDIT 1:**

The merge base is as shown below:

```
uruddarraju$ git merge-base --all HEAD v1.3.4
812b9a47d6625b0fd02af18f9b147720f3c6bfce
```

**EDIT 2:**

I also see the following warning:

```
warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
warning: you may want to set your merge.renamelimit variable to at least 4292 and retry the command.
```

I am clearly missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What commit(s) is/are the merge base(s) of your `HEAD` commit and the commit identified by `v1.3.4`?  That is, run `git merge-base --all HEAD v1.3.4`.  Ideally this will print out a single Git hash, which is the ID of the merge base.  If there are multiple IDs things get a bit more difficult so let's find this first.

Comment: ```LM-SJN-00877661:kubernetes uruddarraju$ git merge-base --all HEAD v1.3.4
812b9a47d6625b0fd02af18f9b147720f3c6bfce```

Answer (score 3):

#### What `git merge` does

In Git, the `merge` operation is used to combine a second line of development into a first line of development.

Suppose that both Alice and Bob are writing some code.  They start with a common version of the code.  Alice adds a new feature, and Bob adds a different new feature.

Along the way, Alice might create or delete files, or modify existing files.  Bob, likewise, might create or delete files.  Let's say, just for argument sake, that Alice is able to make all of her changes without adding or deleting any files, but Bob adds file `n` (for new) and deletes file `o` (for old).

Both Alice and Bob commit their changes—perhaps as one commit, perhaps as many commits—and Alice pushes her work back to `origin` so that Bob can see it.

Now suppose Bob decides to merge Alice's work, i.e., to pick up the changes she has made.  He might run:

```
$ git fetch origin
```

This lets Bob obtain Alice's commits into Bob's repository, under the name `origin/alice`, perhaps.  (The actual name depends on what Alice used when doing her `git push`.)

Next, Bob would run:

```
$ git merge origin/alice
```

This merge must first find the *merge base*: the point at which Alice and Bob diverged and made *different* commits.  Let's assume Bob is on branch `bob`, and draw a commit graph, so that we can see what this "merge base" is:

```
...--o--*--o--o--B     <-- bob
         \
          o--o--o--A   <-- origin/alice
```

In this case, Alice has constructed her feature by making four commits, which added and removed no new files, but presumably modified some existing files.  Bob has constructed his feature by making three commits, some of which added new files (`new`) and/or deleted existing files (`old`).  The merge base is the commit I marked `*`, and the tip of Alice's and Bob's branches are commits `A` and `B` respectively.

Git's job is to *combine* Alice's changes, from the four commits that did not add or delete any files but did modify some files, *plus* Bob's changes, from the three commits that did add and delete files.  If all goes well—if there are no conflicts to resolve—the end result will still have one new file `new`, and one removed file `old`, and Bob will get a new *merge commit* `M`:

```
...--o--*--o--o--B---M   <-- bob
         \          /
          o--o--o--A     <-- origin/alice
```

Before and after this merge, though, if Bob asks Git to diff commits `B` and `A`, he will see some deleted and some added files.  *These are not files Alice added or deleted*; instead, these are the files that Bob himself has added and deleted.

#### Your particular case, vs Bob's

Bob is probably going to have no issues with this, because he probably remembers what he did.  In your case, though, it's more as though you came along after Bob left the group and are now trying to merge Alice's and Bob's changes, with no knowledge about what Bob did.

Since we now know (from the `git merge-base` command output) there's just the one merge base, we can use the three-dot syntax with `git diff` to *compare* that one merge base to the two branch-tips.  This will let us, in effect, "figure out what Bob did" and "figure out what Alice did".

Your commit graph is probably substantially more complex than the one in the example above, too, but *in principle* at least, your task is the same: you have two particular commits `A` and `B` that you are merging, where commit `B` is the `HEAD` commit of your current branch and commit `A` is the one you are identifying by the name `v1.3.4`.  So you have:

```
...--o--*--o--o--B     <-- HEAD
         \
          o--o--o--A   <-- v1.3.4
```

(Aside: even though `v1.3.4` is a tag, it works just as well as a branch here.  The name `HEAD` works as well as your current branch name here, so I am using it instead of the branch name.)

Commit `*` is the merge base—the one whose hash is `812b9a47d6625b0fd02af18f9b147720f3c6bfce`.  We could run these two `git diff` commands:

```
git diff 812b9a47d6625b0fd02af18f9b147720f3c6bfce HEAD
git diff 812b9a47d6625b0fd02af18f9b147720f3c6bfce v1.3.4
```

This requires typing in the hash (or copy-pasting).  Instead, we can use this somewhat shorter form:

```
git diff v1.3.4...HEAD
git diff HEAD...v1.3.4
```

Because there is exactly one merge base (`812b9a47d6625b0fd02af18f9b147720f3c6bfce`), these two sets of commands do the same thing.  The first one shows us "what we did" and the second one shows us "what they did".  Git will attempt to combine these two sets of changes.

(Note that we can add `--name-status` and/or `--stat` to these diff commands to get shorter summaries of what changed, rather than complete diffs.  This may be useful for your case.)

When you get conflicts (as you did), this simply means that Git was not able to reconcile "their" changes (from the second diff) with "our" changes (from the first diff).  If their changes included adding files, Git would have no problem with that: it would add those files.  They would not be missing from the merge result.  Presumably, though, what happened here is that "we" (on "our" branch) *removed* files.

Presumably we did not need those files, but they, in their changes that we are adding to our code by merging, *do* need those files.  Git cannot know this—Git has no idea what any code *means*.  We will simply have to restore those files to some suitable form, and fix up our code, if necessary, to allow those files to exist; or we will have to modify their code so that it works without those files; or some combination of the two.

#### Aside: if there is not exactly one merge bases

It is rare, but not impossible, to have two or more merge bases, or even to have *no* merge base.  In this case, `git merge` knows what to do, but `git diff` does not.  If you encounter this situation, the simple `git diff A...B; git diff B...A` method will not (quite) be able to show you the inputs to the merge process.  There is no easy way to deal with this case.  It's a good idea to check (with `git merge-base --all`) to make sure that this won't be interfering, before using the `git diff A...B` style diffs to figure out what `git merge` is seeing.

Comment: `Presumably, though, what happened here is that "we" (on "our" branch) removed files.` is not True. I am able to `git log -- pkg/genericapiserver/resource_config.go` without any results. Which means I never deleted the file and never had that file in my tree.

Comment: Using `git log` is iffy as it may lie to you if the file was deleted in a merge.  The diff (from base to HEAD) will tell you for sure.